# Plot multiple layers of distinct symmetric planes

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to plot a multilayered system of distinct symmetric planes as shown in the figure below, the system should have a reference label.
I don't know if I can draw it using Mathematica or another software.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can take it from here.

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = 1;
ball = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
c1 = RegionCentroid[ball];

rect3D = Table[{{-2, -2, i}, {2, -2, i}, {2, 2, i}, {-2, 2, i}}, {i, 
    0, -4, -0.5}];

    axes = {
       Arrowheads[0.04]
   
   , {Red, Arrow[Tube[{c1, 2.5 UnitVector[3, 1]}, 0.01]]
    , Text[Style["x", Bold, 14], a UnitVector[3, 1] + {2, 0, 0}]
    , {Black, Dashed, 
     InfiniteLine[{-UnitVector[3, 1], UnitVector[3, 1]}]}
    }
   
   , {Blue, Arrow[Tube[{c1, 2.5 UnitVector[3, 2]}, 0.01]]
    , Text[Style["y", Bold, 14], b UnitVector[3, 2] + {0, 2, 0}]}
   , {Black, Dashed, 
    InfiniteLine[{-UnitVector[3, 2], UnitVector[3, 2]}]}
   
   , {Darker@Green, Arrow[Tube[{c1, 2 UnitVector[3, 3]}, 0.01]]
    , Text[Style["z", Bold, 14], c UnitVector[3, 3] + {0, 0, 2}]}
   , {Black, Dashed, 
    InfiniteLine[{-UnitVector[3, 3], UnitVector[3, 3]}]}
   
   , {
    Arrowheads[0.03], Black, Dashed
    , Arrow[Tube[{c1, Normalize[{2, 2, 2}]}, 0.005]]
    }
   
   , {Black, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@c1}
   , {Opacity[0.2, Lighter@Green], ball}
   };

polys = MapThread[
   {FaceForm[#1], EdgeForm[#2], Polygon@#3} &
   , {
    ConstantArray[White, Length@rect3D]
    , {Thin, Thin, Thin, DotDashed, Dotted, Dashed, Thin, Thin, Thick}
    , rect3D
    }
   ];

text = {
   Text[Style["l == 1", 14, Bold, Black, Italic, 
     "Times"], {-2.3, -2.3, 0}]
   , Text[
    Style["l == 2", 14, Bold, Black, Italic, 
     "Times"], {-2.3`, -2.3`, -0.5`}]
   , Text[
    Style["L", 14, Bold, Red, Italic, "Times"], {-2.3`, -2.3`, -4.`}]
   
   , {Arrowheads[{-0.018, 0.018}], Black
    , Arrow[Tube[{{2.2`, 2.2`, -3.5`}, {2.2`, 2.2`, -4.`}}], 0.0005]
    , Text[
     Style[TraditionalForm[Subscript[J, ll']], Bold, Black, 
      16], {2.4`, 2.4`, -3.75`}]
    }
   
   };

Show[
 Graphics3D[{polys
   , axes
   , text
   }
  , Lighting -> "Neutral"
  , Boxed -> False
  , ImageSize -> 600
  , SphericalRegion -> True
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I have added the ball for no reason, but it may help visualize vectors that are  at different 3D angles.

Answer (score 7):

Here is something to get you started.

You may stack a number of infinite planes. To write text in 3D in a random direction, you may place every character separately.

```
txt[s_, pos_] := Module[{chars = Characters[s], c = 0},
  Text[#, pos + {0.2 c++, 0, 0.2}] & /@ chars
  ]

Graphics3D[{InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 
 0}}], {EdgeForm[Directive[Dashed]], FaceForm[Opacity[0.1]], 
   InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}]}, 
  InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 2}}], 
  txt["Text1", {5, 0, 0}], txt["Text2", {5, 0, 1}], 
  txt["Text3", {5, 0, 2}]}, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 2.5}}]
```

[image]